# jquery: check if window has been scrolled once and do something

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, scroll

Because of a new implementation of the cookie law, I have to gather consent for some cookies. One of the methods, is to wait for the user to scroll the page once, which has been legally meant to be an implicit consent.

I tried with:

```
jQuery(window).one('scroll', function(){
  $(this).data('scrolled', true);
});

if(jQuery(window).data('scrolled')) {
    console.log( 'ok' );
    //place cookies
} else {
    console.log( 'no' );
}
```

inside a script ( http://www.primebox.co.uk/projects/jquery-cookiebar/ ) that is called via:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                $.cookieBar({
                }); 
            });
```

However, console.log always tells me "no", regardless of the scrolling of the page.

Any hints?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine if I change this like this:

```
<script>
    jQuery(window).one('scroll', function()
    {
        $(this).data('scrolled', true);
        if(jQuery(window).data('scrolled'))
        {
            console.log('ok');
            //place cookies
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('no');
        }
    });
</script>
```

However I could not make out what **$.cookieBar** is doing ?

Comment: cookieBar is a generic script (whose source I linked in the first post) that allows the cookies to be put on hold until the user gives the consent. Thanks anyway, this fixed the issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Check scroll and do some thing you want

   window.onscroll = function (e) {
   // called when the window is scrolled.
   }

> This will call every time when user scroll if you want to call it
>   only once then do some trict

1. Make a hidden Field
2. Now set value of this hidden field to true when scroll method call

   window.onscroll = function (e) 
   {
     if (document.getElementById("ScrollOnceCheck").value == "false") 
     {
      document.getElementById("ScrollOnceCheck").value = "true";
      // update cookie
     }
   }

Comment: i am interested to know did it help you out ?

Comment: I chose Rayton Dabre's solution because it was similar to mines, but your idea looks ok good to me.

Comment: that gud if you got the answer.